# probability of a word in emails

Tags: probability, statistics

One of the ways of recognizing "spams", is using the words in the body of the emails. One of these words is "Free". In a set of email, from the whole 5000 emails, 13.5 % is spam. Among these emails, 4.5 % contains the word "Free" and 3.5 % of the emails containing the word "Free", are spams.
A) assuming an email is spam, how much is the probability that it contains the word "Free"?
B) assuming that an email, contains the word "Free", how much is the probability that, this email is not a spam?

I did the first part, which I'm not sure it;s right. but I have no idea for the second part.
F = Free
S = Spam
p(F|S)= p(F)p(S|F)/p(S)= 4.5*3.5/13.5=

Answer (score 0):

A) One way to think about this: $.135$ of $5000$ emails contain spam, that is, there are $675$ spam. $.045$ of the 5000 emails contain "Free" (so 225 emails contain "Free") and $.035$ of the latter are spam (so about 8 spam emails contain "free"). So the probability that a spam email contains "free" is $8/675=.012$.

B) Since $.035$ of the emails with "Free" are spam, it follows that $1-.035 = .965$ of the emails with Free are not spam.

Comment: thanks, but there isn't any mathematical formula?

Comment: we have to prove it for our teacher.

Comment: 1) Yes, you could generalize this using notation like you wrote above. Try going through my answer and represent it that way, although I would consider that this is a proof. 2) Is this a graded assignment? Why are you asking for the answer?

Comment: It's my homework